# Why am I being charged on the very first day of Bluemix trial?

Tags: ibm-cloud, trial

i signed up bluemix, so i am on trial account
I have started learning Kitura along the tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/swift/2016/07/06/tutorial-deploying-a-swift-to-do-list-app-to-the-cloud/#comment-2218

I uploaded the files a several time to make the server run (actually the tutorial gave me wrong link for the files)
now it works.

but I saw my Runtime Cost is $289.
[image]
[image]

I have not added any support plan
although I have not put my credit card info yet, is that what is going to be charged after Trial or for every month ?
Why am I being charged anyway?
nearly $300 is too high for testing a server.
Would you explain about the Runtime Cost that I am currently being charged please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Droppy This tag is IBM's official suppport channel they said. you will see other question like this with the tag

Comment: It's for questions related to *programming* IBM Bluemix.  All other questions relating to that service are off-topic.

Comment: @Droppy I know what you are saying but  i saw people using the tag with questions like log in issue and billing as well. they do that because the IBM guys announced using the tag not only specifically on programming i guess.

Comment: @KyleKIM On https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#ask are SO and dW Answers offered, each with a description of where to ask. Customers can also open support tickets. In this case it would have been a support question or dW Answers. It is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix provides you with a cost calculator that allows you to trace what you will pay for services, containers, and VMs. In your case since you have a trial account, that is only an estimate of what you should pay.